# Does SFINAE allow this?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I am trying to remove member functions from a class template, using std::enable_if. When I disable a function I get the error:

```
C2938: 'std::enable_if_t<false,int64_t>' : Failed to specialize alias template
```

My code looks like this:

```
template<int NUM_COMPONENTS>
struct Foo
{
    typename std::enable_if_t<(NUM_COMPONENTS == 2), void> set(int64 x, int64 y)
    {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

Am I doing something that is not allowed by the standard, if so is there another way to do this? Or is this a bug? I'm using MSVC with QtCreator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The S in SFINAE stands for the substitution of template arguments for template parameters that is done for a *template* when it's considered as a candidate for overload resolution.

`Foo` is a template, but `set` isn't. What happens is that you instantiate `Foo`, which instantiates the declaration of `set`, and the function contains an invalid return type. There's no SFINAE to be had, because this bit of substitution doesn't occur prior to overload resolution.

To apply SFINAE, you must make `set` a template:

```
template<int NUM = NUM_COMPONENTS>
std::enable_if_t<(NUM== 2), void> set(int64 x, int64 y)
{
    // some code here
}
```

Now you get a valid declaration (of a template). But when you'll try to *call* it, another substitution will occurs, for which SFINAE applies.

As a bonus, C++20 makes this exercise moot. What you want to achieve will be possible with a simple `requires` clause:

```
void set(int64 x, int64 y) requires (NUM_COMPONENTS == 2)
{
    // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only aim at prohibiting this particular function for a given template parameters rather than to make this overload less preferred then the simpler solution is to put a `static_assert` inside of function body. Function body will be instantiated only when you actually try invoke this function, while function declaration is instantiated along with class itself:

```
void set(int x, int y)
{
    static_assert(NUM_COMPONENTS == 2);
}
```

Comment: I considered this as well, bu choose not to because I wasn't sure code completion tools would be able to recognise that the function is not part of the class. Do you know about this?

Comment: @AartOdding What do you mean by "the function is not part of the class"? It is part of the class, but can not be instantiated.